# Why does fish shell create a hidden process in iTerm2

Tags: command-line, shell, iterm2, fish

I've moved from bash to fish shell in iTerm2. However, whenever I start iTerm2, I receive the following error message:

> A session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in
>   profile is correct.

After looking around, I realise that whenever I start iTerm2 for the first time, it creates two processes:

```
40776   ??  S      0:00.41 /Users/admin/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
40778 s000  Ss     0:00.03 /Users/admin/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp admin
```

The first process terminates when I quit iTerm2, but the second one remains. I have to manually kill it.

I don't have this problem with bash or even zsh. So, why does fish shell create an additional and hidden process, and how to stop it from doing so?

Comment: Insufficient data. Fish is not creating that process. iTerm is. The error that iTerm2 reports means the process it launched, presumably a fish login shell, exited very quickly. Did you run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` to set it as your login shell? Are you even able to start a iTerm2 instance? If you are is it running fish or something else (e.g., bash)? If something else what happens if you type `fish -l`?